# Cannot find name 'Schema' in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Here's file structure:

In `m.ts`:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const {Schema} = mongoose;
export {Schema};
```

In `a.ts`:

```
import {Schema} from './m';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const a: Schema = new Schema({}); // Cannot find name 'Schema'
const b: mongoose.Schema = new Schema({}); // this works...
```

The first statement throws an error saying `Cannot find name 'Schema'` while second statement works. This seems odd to me. Can someone explain why this is the case?

Is there a way that I don't have to import directly from `mongoose` everytime I use it?

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose.Schema` is a class, not is a const or a function, in typescript you can not set class defined to a const(variable), this mean you can not rename a class.
ex:

```
    const staffClass = Model.UserClass;
    let emp = new staffClass(); // are you think `emp` will be a instance of `UserClass`? 
    // No, you do not have any class with name `staffClass` as your issue
```

If you want to create a object with `new` keyword, you have to define a class.

`m.ts`

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
class Schema extends mongoose.Schema {

}
export {Schema}
```

Just create a new class called `Schema` in your namespace, the class is a child of `mongoose.Schema`.